# How to set way to git in IDEA in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, intellij-idea

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu, then installed Intellij IDEA and imported my settings from the Windows version. Now if I want to import my project from github an error occurs:
"Cannot run program "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd/git.exe": error=2, No such file or directory." How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open the settings dialog ([Control+Alt+s](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/accessing-the-ide-settings.html))
- Open the Version Control > Git item
- Edit the "Path to Git executable:" and set it to the path to your system's git executable

Comment: Thank you. In addition, my "Path to Git executable:" now is "/usr/bin/git"

Comment: You can check the location of git using the command `whereis git`.

Comment: I've tested here and checked that this also works in wsl (windows subsystem for linux). In my case the 'path to git executable' is "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\git"